# CSS file not displaying despite using app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am attempting to link `test.css` to `test.html`. I attempted to use `javascript
router.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`
 in `app.js` to hopefully fish out the file from the folder `public` but to no avail.

I also attempted to do `href="/public/test.css"` and `href="/test.css"` in the link of the html file but nothing changed. I also thought of putting the line 
`router.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` 
in `index.js` but once again, didn't work.
file directory:

```
server file
 |
 bin---www.js
 node_modules
 public---test.css
 routes---index.js
 views
 app.js
 server.js
 test.html
 package.json
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var path = require('path');
var port = require('port');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const queryString = require('query-string');

var routes = require('./routes/index.js');
var app = express();

router.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// view engine setup
app.engine('hbs', hbs({
    extname: 'hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'index',
    layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views'
}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'Views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));


app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var userData = db.get('user-data');
var app = require('express')();

router.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('test');
});

module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

function onRequest(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    fs.readFile('./test.html', null, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write('File not found!');
        } else {
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
```

Comment: Just asking, why is your app.js file never used in server.js? why would you `module.exports=app` in the app.js file? I didn't see any `require('./app.js')`, You use the `app.use()` for static files but never use it.

Comment: Try app.use(express.static('public')) and remove public prefix in html file for calling CSS